# Generating an email alert for new post in site feed

Tags: email, alert, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am working with sharepoint online 2013 and Sharepoint designer 2013.

I wanted to generate an email alert for the Site Feed App (Micro Feed). I wanted to send an email to a group of people with the posted content and the name of the person who posted the content. I tried the method explained in the following question.

"I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are created or updated"

It worked for the other lists(Document Libraries etc) But the workflow i created for Site Feed only generates and email when a user replies to a post. I tried almost all the combinations in the Start Options of Workflow Settings.

http://goo.gl/9HznDG

How can change the settings of the workflow so that it generate an email for a new post in site feed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my colleagues found out a solution for this.

First we have to create a Site workflow for this.Not a list workflow for site feed.

In the site workflow we have to create a loop.

[image: Site Workflow]

In the workflow first we have to create an infinite loop and wait for a item adding event for Microfeed list.

[image]

Then in the email action we can add lookups for the attributes in the item.

[image]

In the add look up window we can use following settings to get the values in the item.

[image]

Save and publish the workflow.
Now it will send an email to the users mentioned in the workflow once a new post is added to the site feed/news feed/micro feed.